# Bootstrap popover does not update angularjs ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap popover to show some information when click on the popover.Once popover is clicked it execute a REST call and bind the values to ng-modal.But popover template doesn't update.Please let me know how to fix this.

**Note:** When second time click on popover template get updated.

**HTML code snippet**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="loadEmpDetails()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" data-toggle="popover" title="<strong class='txt-color-white'>Employee Details</strong>" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Popover Left" data-html="true" data-content='<div class="userDiv ">UserName : {{userName}} </Div>>Info</a>
```

**AngularJs code snippet**

```
$scope.loadEmpDetails=function(){
      MYService.EmpDetails.getDetails({},empDTO)
       .$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.userName=data.userName; //This value did not bind to html template
           etc...
        }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to update the Bootstrap popover content dynamically.But this is not related with AngularJs but simply it does the trick.The solution is instead of calling `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` in `document.ready` you can call it inside your function.Then it will update the popover content dynamically.

```
$scope.loadEmpDetails=function(){
      MYService.EmpDetails.getDetails({},empDTO)
       .$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.userName=data.userName; //This value did not bind to html template
           etc...
        //Draw popover
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

        }
        };
```